# How can I calculate background-position in percentage? Convert background-position pixels to percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a < div > element

I know:

width: 500px,

height: 250px,

background-size: "240% 320%" or "1200px 800px",

background-position: -807px -526px,

also I know original image size: { width: 600px height: 400px }

**I need to calculate background-position in percents**

and not only for this case, I need to do it dynamic, so need a formula

Comment: What if you use % in background position?
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/

Comment: Just replace 'px' to '%'?

Comment: What is the purpose of this requirement? to fit in the image in the `Div`?

Comment: No, I need to convert pixels to percentages. It's not to make the image fit anywhere. User himself can dynamically move a picture in the background, I calculated the pixels. Now I need to convert them as a percentage so that when you scale div, the background-image will be scaled too.

Comment: in the duplicate you will find a section called "Relation between pixel and percentage values" and also at the end "Make percentage behave differently"